# When text input is filled, button doesn't submit

Tags: react-native

The button's onPress function is called when neither of text fields above are filled. Otherwise, I press the button and nothing happens. I've tried change the `onPress` to `onPress={this.handleSubmit()}` but then the function is called before any data is in the TextInput's and an error is thrown. I've also tried using the tcomb-form-native package, but the problem persists. What do I need to change to get the handleSubmit function to be called when the text inputs are filled?

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log('handle submit')
}    

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder="Your name"
      onChangeText={userName => this.setState({userName})}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder="other name"
      onChangeText={otherName => this.setState({otherName})}
    />
    <Button
      title="Name"
      onPress={this.handleSubmit}
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
e.preventDefault()
```

?

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
  console.log('handle submit')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: '',
        otherName: ''
    };
}

handleSubmit = () => {
    // Check if any of them is empty then do nothing
    if(!this.state.otherName || !this.state.userName){return;}
    console.log('handle submit');
  }    
  
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Your name"
        onChangeText={userName => this.setState({userName})}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="other name"
        onChangeText={otherName => this.setState({otherName})}
      />
      <Button
        title="Name"
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
      />
    </View>
  );
  }
```